# Storing two different types in QModelIndex

Tags: c++, qt

I have a graph represented by `Node`s and `Edge`s and I have written an adaptor so I can view the graph in a tabular form using Qt standard views like so:

```
Node1
   -Edge1
       -Node2
   -Edge2
       -Node3
   -Edge3
       -Node1
Node2
Node3
   -Edge4
       -Node1
```

I did it making use of the overloads for `QAbstractItemModel::createIndex` to store either an index position (`quintptr` overload) or pointer to correct item (`void*` overload). However that was foolish because it does not actually matter what overload one uses there is always just one value that is just converted for both `QModelIndex::internalPointer()` and `QModelIndex::internalID()`. Needless to say it creates conflicts that crashes the model under certain circumstances which is how I found out it was a bad idea.

Now I cannot figure out what to store as a third variable in the `QModelIndex` so that I could distinguish between:

1) Index points to an edge under some node

2) Index points to a node under some edge

The empty value is currently being "used" to identify top level nodes. What should I store in these two cases to reliably identify the parent? Is there even a way to store two different "things" (other than "nothing" and "one type of something") in the `QModelIndex`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create your graph as a separated data structure. Your *node* and *edge* objects will have an *unique ID*. And than use this ID inside the `QModelIndex`.

**Edit 1: How to distinguish node from edge.**

```
class CGraphElement
{
public:
    enum Type
    {
        Node,
        Edge
    }

    CGraphElement(Type type) : m_type(type) {}

    bool isNode() const { return m_type == Node; }
    bool isEdge() const { return m_type == Edge; }

private:
    Type m_type;

};

// container mapping ID to graph Element (Node or Edge)
std::map<int, CGraphElement> mapId2Element;

void functionDealingWithModelIndex(const QModelIndex & index)
{
    int id = index.internalID();
    CGraphElement* element = mapId2Element[id];
    if (element->isEdge())
        qDebug() << "Edge";
    else if (element->isNode())
        qDebug() << "Node";
}
```

Comment: I am not sure how I could create a unique ID that make it apparent from the id itself that the thing it points to is a node or an edge plus the information where to locate it. I indeed do have ids but they are indices to the respective locations where to find the item but does not bear information what that object is (node or edge). So far my only idea is to create base class that could tell me that distinction (using bool member) and static_cast based on that.

Answer (score 0):

Check out [QVariant](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qvariant.html) and (maybe) [qRegisterMetaType](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qmetatype.html#qRegisterMetaType-1).