# PyQt: Storing complex metadata in QModelIndex's internalPointer

Tags: python, qt, pyqt5, qtreeview

This might be more appropriate as a bug report, but maybe I'm just misunderstanding something.

I want to implement my own hierarchical QAbstractItemModel to show a tree of objects in a QTreeView. I've started with the editable tree model example [1] which works fine.

However, I need more metadata in my indexes as I have differend types of nodes (or rather nodes have properties) and a simple (row, column, object-pointer)-tuple is not enough. See also [Storing two different types in QModelIndex](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35990329/storing-two-different-types-in-qmodelindex) for another example.

So I've created another datastructure which holds this data:

```
# this is just an example
class TempContainer:
    def __init__(self, name, obj):
        self.name = name
        self.obj = obj
```

And I create an index like this:

```
# in TreeModel.index():
o = TempContainer("child", childItem)
self.tmpcache.append(o) # just to keep a reference alive
return self.createIndex(row, column, o)
```

Accessing objects can now be implemented as follows:

```
def getItem(self, index):
    if index.isValid():
        item = index.internalPointer()
        if item:
            return item.obj

    return self.rootItem
```

But if I add this layer of metadata, selecting and editing items does not work anymore. I can still select cells in first colum of root items and edit all items in the first column. But eg. selecting sub-items or items in the second column doesn't work anymore!

I've noticed that it works if I store my TempContainer inside the corresponding TreeItem, but this is not really an option as there are a multiple containers that point to the same item in my full code.

I'm running python 3.5.3 under Linux (Fedora 24), with PyQt 5.6.2 (I've also tried 5.8.2) and Qt 5.6.2.

---

[1] Unfortunately, I cannot attach a ZIP of the full source, but the code is available under https://www.riverbankcomputing.com/software/pyqt/download5, in `/examples/itemviews/editabletreemodel`

---

The full source of the modified editabletreemodel.py:
(Note that I only modified a few lines and that you will still need the other files from the example to run this.)

```
#!/usr/bin/env python


#############################################################################
##
## Copyright (C) 2013 Riverbank Computing Limited.
## Copyright (C) 2010 Nokia Corporation and/or its subsidiary(-ies).
## All rights reserved.
##
## This file is part of the examples of PyQt.
##
## $QT_BEGIN_LICENSE:BSD$
## You may use this file under the terms of the BSD license as follows:
##
## "Redistribution and use in source and binary forms, with or without
## modification, are permitted provided that the following conditions are
## met:
##   * Redistributions of source code must retain the above copyright
##     notice, this list of conditions and the following disclaimer.
##   * Redistributions in binary form must reproduce the above copyright
##     notice, this list of conditions and the following disclaimer in
##     the documentation and/or other materials provided with the
##     distribution.
##   * Neither the name of Nokia Corporation and its Subsidiary(-ies) nor
##     the names of its contributors may be used to endorse or promote
##     products derived from this software without specific prior written
##     permission.
##
## THIS SOFTWARE IS PROVIDED BY THE COPYRIGHT HOLDERS AND CONTRIBUTORS
## "AS IS" AND ANY EXPRESS OR IMPLIED WARRANTIES, INCLUDING, BUT NOT
## LIMITED TO, THE IMPLIED WARRANTIES OF MERCHANTABILITY AND FITNESS FOR
## A PARTICULAR PURPOSE ARE DISCLAIMED. IN NO EVENT SHALL THE COPYRIGHT
## OWNER OR CONTRIBUTORS BE LIABLE FOR ANY DIRECT, INDIRECT, INCIDENTAL,
## SPECIAL, EXEMPLARY, OR CONSEQUENTIAL DAMAGES (INCLUDING, BUT NOT
## LIMITED TO, PROCUREMENT OF SUBSTITUTE GOODS OR SERVICES; LOSS OF USE,
## DATA, OR PROFITS; OR BUSINESS INTERRUPTION) HOWEVER CAUSED AND ON ANY
## THEORY OF LIABILITY, WHETHER IN CONTRACT, STRICT LIABILITY, OR TORT
## (INCLUDING NEGLIGENCE OR OTHERWISE) ARISING IN ANY WAY OUT OF THE USE
## OF THIS SOFTWARE, EVEN IF ADVISED OF THE POSSIBILITY OF SUCH DAMAGE."
## $QT_END_LICENSE$
##
#############################################################################


from PyQt5.QtCore import (QAbstractItemModel, QFile, QIODevice,
        QItemSelectionModel, QModelIndex, Qt)
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QApplication, QMainWindow

import editabletreemodel_rc
from ui_mainwindow import Ui_MainWindow


class TreeItem(object):
    def __init__(self, data, parent=None):
        self.parentItem = parent
        self.itemData = data
        self.childItems = []

    def child(self, row):
        return self.childItems[row]

    def childCount(self):
        return len(self.childItems)

    def childNumber(self):
        if self.parentItem != None:
            return self.parentItem.childItems.index(self)
        return 0

    def columnCount(self):
        return len(self.itemData)

    def data(self, column):
        return self.itemData[column]

    def insertChildren(self, position, count, columns):
        if position < 0 or position > len(self.childItems):
            return False

        for row in range(count):
            data = [None for v in range(columns)]
            item = TreeItem(data, self)
            self.childItems.insert(position, item)

        return True

    def insertColumns(self, position, columns):
        if position < 0 or position > len(self.itemData):
            return False

        for column in range(columns):
            self.itemData.insert(position, None)

        for child in self.childItems:
            child.insertColumns(position, columns)

        return True

    def parent(self):
        return self.parentItem

    def removeChildren(self, position, count):
        if position < 0 or position + count > len(self.childItems):
            return False

        for row in range(count):
            self.childItems.pop(position)

        return True

    def removeColumns(self, position, columns):
        if position < 0 or position + columns > len(self.itemData):
            return False

        for column in range(columns):
            self.itemData.pop(position)

        for child in self.childItems:
            child.removeColumns(position, columns)

        return True

    def setData(self, column, value):
        if column < 0 or column >= len(self.itemData):
            return False

        self.itemData[column] = value

        return True


class TempContainer:
    def __init__(self, name, obj):
        self.name = name
        self.obj = obj

class TreeModel(QAbstractItemModel):
    def __init__(self, headers, data, parent=None):
        super(TreeModel, self).__init__(parent)

        rootData = [header for header in headers]
        self.rootItem = TreeItem(rootData)
        self.setupModelData(data.split("\n"), self.rootItem)

        self.tmpcache = []

    def columnCount(self, parent=QModelIndex()):
        return self.rootItem.columnCount()

    def data(self, index, role):
        if not index.isValid():
            return None

        if role != Qt.DisplayRole and role != Qt.EditRole:
            return None

        item = self.getItem(index)
        return item.data(index.column())

    def flags(self, index):
        if not index.isValid():
            return 0

        return Qt.ItemIsEditable | Qt.ItemIsEnabled | Qt.ItemIsSelectable

    def getItem(self, index):
        if index.isValid():
            item = index.internalPointer()
            if item:
                return item.obj

        return self.rootItem

    def headerData(self, section, orientation, role=Qt.DisplayRole):
        if orientation == Qt.Horizontal and role == Qt.DisplayRole:
            return self.rootItem.data(section)

        return None

    def index(self, row, column, parent=QModelIndex()):
        if parent.isValid() and parent.column() != 0:
            return QModelIndex()

        parentItem = self.getItem(parent)
        childItem = parentItem.child(row)
        if childItem:
            o = TempContainer("child", childItem)
            self.tmpcache.append(o)
            return self.createIndex(row, column, o)
        else:
            return QModelIndex()

    def insertColumns(self, position, columns, parent=QModelIndex()):
        self.beginInsertColumns(parent, position, position + columns - 1)
        success = self.rootItem.insertColumns(position, columns)
        self.endInsertColumns()

        return success

    def insertRows(self, position, rows, parent=QModelIndex()):
        parentItem = self.getItem(parent)
        self.beginInsertRows(parent, position, position + rows - 1)
        success = parentItem.insertChildren(position, rows,
                self.rootItem.columnCount())
        self.endInsertRows()

        return success

    def parent(self, index):
        if not index.isValid():
            return QModelIndex()

        childItem = self.getItem(index)
        parentItem = childItem.parent()

        if parentItem == self.rootItem:
            return QModelIndex()

        o = TempContainer("parent", parentItem)
        self.tmpcache.append(o)
        return self.createIndex(parentItem.childNumber(), 0, o)

    def removeColumns(self, position, columns, parent=QModelIndex()):
        self.beginRemoveColumns(parent, position, position + columns - 1)
        success = self.rootItem.removeColumns(position, columns)
        self.endRemoveColumns()

        if self.rootItem.columnCount() == 0:
            self.removeRows(0, self.rowCount())

        return success

    def removeRows(self, position, rows, parent=QModelIndex()):
        parentItem = self.getItem(parent)

        self.beginRemoveRows(parent, position, position + rows - 1)
        success = parentItem.removeChildren(position, rows)
        self.endRemoveRows()

        return success

    def rowCount(self, parent=QModelIndex()):
        parentItem = self.getItem(parent)

        return parentItem.childCount()

    def setData(self, index, value, role=Qt.EditRole):
        if role != Qt.EditRole:
            return False

        item = self.getItem(index)
        result = item.setData(index.column(), value)

        if result:
            self.dataChanged.emit(index, index)

        return result

    def setHeaderData(self, section, orientation, value, role=Qt.EditRole):
        if role != Qt.EditRole or orientation != Qt.Horizontal:
            return False

        result = self.rootItem.setData(section, value)
        if result:
            self.headerDataChanged.emit(orientation, section, section)

        return result

    def setupModelData(self, lines, parent):
        parents = [parent]
        indentations = [0]

        number = 0

        while number < len(lines):
            position = 0
            while position < len(lines[number]):
                if lines[number][position] != " ":
                    break
                position += 1

            lineData = lines[number][position:].trimmed()

            if lineData:
                # Read the column data from the rest of the line.
                columnData = [s for s in lineData.split('\t') if s]

                if position > indentations[-1]:
                    # The last child of the current parent is now the new
                    # parent unless the current parent has no children.

                    if parents[-1].childCount() > 0:
                        parents.append(parents[-1].child(parents[-1].childCount() - 1))
                        indentations.append(position)

                else:
                    while position < indentations[-1] and len(parents) > 0:
                        parents.pop()
                        indentations.pop()

                # Append a new item to the current parent's list of children.
                parent = parents[-1]
                parent.insertChildren(parent.childCount(), 1,
                        self.rootItem.columnCount())
                for column in range(len(columnData)):
                    parent.child(parent.childCount() -1).setData(column, columnData[column])

            number += 1


class MainWindow(QMainWindow, Ui_MainWindow):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(MainWindow, self).__init__(parent)

        self.setupUi(self)

        headers = ("Title", "Description")

        file = QFile(':/default.txt')
        file.open(QIODevice.ReadOnly)
        model = TreeModel(headers, file.readAll())
        file.close()

        self.view.setModel(model)
        for column in range(model.columnCount()):
            self.view.resizeColumnToContents(column)

        self.exitAction.triggered.connect(QApplication.instance().quit)

        self.view.selectionModel().selectionChanged.connect(self.updateActions)

        self.actionsMenu.aboutToShow.connect(self.updateActions)
        self.insertRowAction.triggered.connect(self.insertRow)
        self.insertColumnAction.triggered.connect(self.insertColumn)
        self.removeRowAction.triggered.connect(self.removeRow)
        self.removeColumnAction.triggered.connect(self.removeColumn)
        self.insertChildAction.triggered.connect(self.insertChild)

        self.updateActions()

    def insertChild(self):
        index = self.view.selectionModel().currentIndex()
        model = self.view.model()

        if model.columnCount(index) == 0:
            if not model.insertColumn(0, index):
                return

        if not model.insertRow(0, index):
            return

        for column in range(model.columnCount(index)):
            child = model.index(0, column, index)
            model.setData(child, "[No data]", Qt.EditRole)
            if model.headerData(column, Qt.Horizontal) is None:
                model.setHeaderData(column, Qt.Horizontal, "[No header]",
                        Qt.EditRole)

        self.view.selectionModel().setCurrentIndex(model.index(0, 0, index),
                QItemSelectionModel.ClearAndSelect)
        self.updateActions()

    def insertColumn(self):
        model = self.view.model()
        column = self.view.selectionModel().currentIndex().column()

        changed = model.insertColumn(column + 1)
        if changed:
            model.setHeaderData(column + 1, Qt.Horizontal, "[No header]",
                    Qt.EditRole)

        self.updateActions()

        return changed

    def insertRow(self):
        index = self.view.selectionModel().currentIndex()
        model = self.view.model()

        if not model.insertRow(index.row()+1, index.parent()):
            return

        self.updateActions()

        for column in range(model.columnCount(index.parent())):
            child = model.index(index.row()+1, column, index.parent())
            model.setData(child, "[No data]", Qt.EditRole)

    def removeColumn(self):
        model = self.view.model()
        column = self.view.selectionModel().currentIndex().column()

        changed = model.removeColumn(column)
        if changed:
            self.updateActions()

        return changed

    def removeRow(self):
        index = self.view.selectionModel().currentIndex()
        model = self.view.model()

        if (model.removeRow(index.row(), index.parent())):
            self.updateActions()

    def updateActions(self):
        hasSelection = not self.view.selectionModel().selection().isEmpty()
        self.removeRowAction.setEnabled(hasSelection)
        self.removeColumnAction.setEnabled(hasSelection)

        hasCurrent = self.view.selectionModel().currentIndex().isValid()
        self.insertRowAction.setEnabled(hasCurrent)
        self.insertColumnAction.setEnabled(hasCurrent)

        if hasCurrent:
            self.view.closePersistentEditor(self.view.selectionModel().currentIndex())

            row = self.view.selectionModel().currentIndex().row()
            column = self.view.selectionModel().currentIndex().column()
            if self.view.selectionModel().currentIndex().parent().isValid():
                self.statusBar().showMessage("Position: (%d,%d)" % (row, column))
            else:
                self.statusBar().showMessage("Position: (%d,%d) in top level" % (row, column))


if __name__ == '__main__':

    import sys

    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    window = MainWindow()
    window.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

---

**EDIT:**

I realize the example I gave is rather pointless, `TempContainer` serves no real purpose! It is just a minimal example that shows the problem I ran into. As to why `TempContainer` is required, suppose your actual `TreeItems` looks like this:

```
class TreeItem:
    def __init__(self,
                 name:str, description:str,
                 data:List[TreeItem], metadata:Dict[str,str],
                 parent:TreeItem=None):
        ...
```

Which should be rendered in the TableView as:

```
itemA                somedescription here
itemB                this is another item
 \--metadata
 |    \--created     yesterday
 |    \--color       green
 \--data
      \--itemC       this is a sub-item of itemB
      |    \--metadata
      |    \--data
      \--itemD       and another item
```

Then you would need an index to e.g. 'name of the second metadata item of itemB'. You could create some sort of shadow-tree which reflects this structure but consists of normal `TreeItem`s, but this might get cumbersome, especially with editing. My idea was to store in the index not only a pointer to a `TreeItem` but also annotate it with a sub-index, indicating which part of a `TreeItem` we're pointing at.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The indexes you are creating are almost OK, I think, but they have to fulfil a little bit more of the contract.  Specifically they need to support a valid equals method.  In your model `index` method you create a new `TempContainer` inside the index.  That means that when the view compares that index with another one it has earlier requested for the same place in the tree, then they won't compare equal.  That's because it's using the default equals on the `QModelIndex` class which compares `row`, `column`, and `internalPointer` for equality.  The docs say:

> All values in the model index are used when comparing with another
>   model index

While your `TempContainer` idea seems initially attractive as a way of adapting your tree to the view, this is not easy to do, as you are finding.  Qt essentially expects the model to have a clear tree structure matching that in the view, and it's difficult to avoid.  In cases like this I have always created a tree layer of Python objects whose references I use as the internalPointer.

Comment: Thanks for the quick answer!
Hm, but if the equal operator of `QModelIndex` only compares row, column and parent then the value of internalPointer shouldn't affect it, right?
Edit:
And for not moving the `TempContainer` into `TreeItem`:
I actually have indexes to multiple parts of a single `TreeItem` (this is not shown in my example, sorry). Imagine each `TreeItem` also has a `metadata` dictionary which should appear as a subtree in the view besides the normal children.

Comment: Yeah, sorry, not parent, but internalPointer.  There is no parent in 'QModelIndex`.

Comment: ah, hm... can I override the `__eq__` method of `TempContainer` then?

Comment: Not sure that the QModelIndex will call it.  You could try.  But I am not convinced you need to create indexes referring to the same place but with a different value in the internalPointer.  Pretty sure that's a bad idea.

Comment: Hm, I think I see. So I basically have to re-use my `TempContainer` instances so as to not change the internalPointer whenever I create an index that points to the same thing.

Comment: yeah but I don't see what the TempContainer adds to the TreeItem

Comment: Nothing in this example. Let me edit my original question to show why I [think I] need the container.

Comment: I've just tried overloading `__eq__` and `__ne__` of `TempContainer` but to no avail. `QModelIndex` appearantly doesn't call any comparison operator on its internalPointer (which makes sense as this is all C++ and just a raw pointer).
Also, reusing existing `TempContainers` instead of creating new ones every time fixes the issue. So this really is the source of my problem.

Comment: Regarding your edit (creating a tree layer in python): Don't you have to implement everything twice in this case? Editing, insertion/removal, drag'n'drop, ...?
Implementing `__hash__()` and `__eq__()` and then caching my `TempContainer`s in a dict works as well, even tough it's a bit ugly ;)

Comment: The tree layer can be trivial as long as it is 1-1 to the tree in the view.  It's only the model that needs to implement all those methods and it can do it sensibly using its understanding of the relationship between the real tree and the tree layer.  Which might be what you mean by keeping the `TempContainer`s in a dict :-)

Comment: Hm, okay. And even if the underlaying data gets changed the model has to be notified anyways, so I would just rebuild the tree layer.

Ha, no, I simply meant replacing `tmpcache` with a dict and returing the cached entries ;) Yeah, it's ugly...

Well, I think that concludes this, thank you very much for your help!